# php codes execute squence

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a question about how does php code execute.

I am now only using php to connect to the mysql DB for iOs APP. So I create different APIs at php side. Then, at APP side, just submit post or get request to inquiry or update the DB.

So at php side, I did DB inquiry or update then return a json result to the APP.

Now I have a function, it does the following job:

```
function a(){
  1.Insert a record to the DB;
   if (insert successful){
      2. $this->echoJson ('Succeed','New Record has added');

      3. then send email to several email addresses.(using PHPMailer-master)
    }

}
```

When my APP side get the json data that indicates insertion is successful. The app will jump to another page.

The function works well. The only problem is step 3 takes around 5 seconds to run. Step 1 and 2 is very fast. It seems for the php side, it only returns the json data when all the codes have been executed. So my APP side needs to wait for 5 seconds to get the response. But I only care about if the insertion is successful.

Is it possible to return the json data once the insertion is successful then do the sending?

I am not sure if I explain the problem clearly.

In summary, I found the execution order is step 1 step 3 step 2. I want to make the order as step 1 step 2 step 3.

Thank you.

Comment: You may run step3 in a separate scripts, triggered if the process was successful

Comment: I have posted an answer, but please edit your post to use the best English you can. In particular do not shorten "something" to "sth." That is probably why you have downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your PHPMailer funtion to another file (lets say `send.php`, which can be reached internally by `http://example.com/send.php`). Then you can make a curl request with a tiny timeout function that actually sends the mail.

#### Step 3 becomes:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/send.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 1);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Thank you, Victory. If I want to pass several parameters to send.php, how should I do that? CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

Comment: Thank you, Victory. If I want to pass several parameters to send.php, how should I do that? Is it like: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDL, parmArray); Then, I define parmArry=arrary('parm1'->value1,'parm2'->value2...); But what I should do if I need to pass a file or image data?

Comment: Hi, Victory. I have tried your solution. If I remove "curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 1); ", the email will be sent. But I still need to wait really long time. If I keep "curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 1);", no emails will be sent. I guess the timeout is too short to execute the page send.php.

Answer (score 1):

Vicotry's solution works with minor edit:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "sendActiveEmail.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 10);
$parmArray=array("paraName"=>value,...);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parmArray);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand your issue but no, it must finish sending the mails before the json returns. PHP does not support threading unlike other High level language, if there is a way you keep the mails like in DB and run a cron job at a time to push all mails and not sending it when its returning the json